# Android - How to add days to date

Tags: android, date

I have retrieved a Date from a SQLiteDatabase and have formatted it to how I want via the following;

```
String steepingDate = (c.getString(3));
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
Date steepingdate = formatter.parse(steepingDate);
```

I now want to give the user the option to increase whatever date is in steepingdate by a certain amount of days that the user can input

I know you can use;

```
Date today = calendar.getTime();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 10);
```

For example to add 10 days onto todays date

But how do you do it so that it uses steepingdate instead of todays date

Thanks

UPDATE;

The calendar is working as I want, but I now want to save the new data to the database, the full code is as following;

```
String steepingDate = (c.getString(3));
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
Date steepingdate = formatter.parse(steepingDate);

Integer amountDays = Integer.parseInt(TSExtend.getText().toString());

Calendar ca = Calendar.getInstance();
ca.setTime(steepingdate);
ca.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, amountDays);

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
String newDate = dateFormat.format(ca);
```

I'm getting the error;

Bad class: class 
java.util.GregorianCalendar

Any ideas?

Comment: do you want to add ten days to steepingDate ?

Comment: That is my example, the amount of days will be determined by the user which I can get the int from the editText but not sure how to add the number to steepingDate

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To add 10 days to `steepingdate`, you can use:

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.setTime(steepingdate);
 calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 10);
```

it the number is provided, through the user interface, you can use the `View.OnClickListener` and when onClick is fired, read the value from an `EditText`, and use this value instead of 10

Comment: Hi @Blackbelt, I've edited my post please see updates to see if you have a solution

Comment: is it compile time or runtime ?

Answer (score 6):

Set the time of the calendar to your date, then add the days

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(steepingdate);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 10);
```

UPDATE:

You can't directly format a Calendar, first get the Date from the Calendar, then format it.

```
String newDate = dateFormat.format(ca.getTime());
```

Comment: hi andrew, can you look at my question as having more difficulties